# llamar api rest en un metodo para usarlo en un button

Tags: angular

Estoy trabajando con Angular y en mi ngOnInit tengo uno de mis services, este mismo me devuelve un ID. Donde almaceno el dato que me devuelve en `this.ultId`. Un dato importante es que cuando saco el services de mi ngOnInit la variable `ultId` me la devuelve como `undefined`

```
  this.tramitesService.getID().subscribe(ID => {
  this.ultId = ID;
})
```

Lo que yo quiero es sacar este service del ngOnInit y ejecutarlo en un metodo, que este metodo se ejecuta dentro de otro.

metodo hijo:

```
  uploadFiles(formData: any): Observable<any> {
          this.tramitesService.getID().subscribe(ID => {
          this.ultId = ID;
          })
          let id = Number(this.ultId)+1
          const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tramites/' + id + '?_method=PUT', formData, {
            reportProgress: true,
            headers: new HttpHeaders().append('enctype', 'multipart/form-data')
        });
          return this.http.request(req);
        }
```

metodo padre:

```
let sec = this.myIdentificador.split('-')[1];
let cod = this.myIdentificador.split('-')[0];
let tram = this.ultTramite;
tramiteForm.value.NroTramite = Number(tram);
tramiteForm.value.SectorDer  = Number(sec);
tramiteForm.value.CodTramite = Number(cod);
forkJoin({
        requestOne: this.tramitesService.saveTramite(tramiteForm.value),
        requestTwo: this.uploadFiles(this.formData),
      }).subscribe(({requestOne, requestTwo})=> {
        console.log(requestOne);
        console.log(requestTwo);
      });
      tramiteForm.reset();
      this.dialog.open(SuccessAlert);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que buscas es un `switchMap` para poder retornar un observable una vez de que se complete tramitesService.

```
uploadFiles(formData: any): Observable<any> {
          return this.tramitesService.getID()
           .pipe(switchMap(ID)=>{
                this.ultId = ID;
                let id = Number(this.ultId)+1
                const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tramites/' + id + '?_method=PUT', formData, 
                {
                 reportProgress: true,
                 headers: new HttpHeaders().append('enctype', 'multipart/form-data')
                });
                return this.http.request(req);
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude solucionar con un toPromise().then. Acá el código por si alguien se encuentra con el mismo problema.

```
this.tramitesService.getUltTramite().toPromise().then((maxTram)=>{console.log(maxTram),
            this.tramitesService.saveTramite(tramiteForm.value, maxTram).toPromise().then((data)=> {console.log(data),
              this.uploadFiles(this.formData,data.RComunicInter_ID)
             })
          })
```